# Language.Haskell.Interpreter - how to properly call IO actions?

Tags: haskell, interpreter, monads, ghc-api

Following the [example file](http://code.haskell.org/hint/devel/examples/example.hs), I try to dynamically call an IO action.

```
testHint :: Interpreter ()
testHint = do
                setImportsQ [("Prelude", Nothing)]
                let somecode = "putStrLn \"some string\""
                interpret somecode (as :: IO ())
                say "hello"
```

Unfortunately, the string `"some string"` is never printed. I also tried to call `writeFile` but no file was created, either.

So what is needed to enable these side effects? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`interpret` won't run any `IO` actions on its own. It'll just evaluate it and return it to you and then you have to run it yourself, for example using `liftIO`:

```
interpret somecode (as :: IO ()) >>= liftIO
```